# Python recursive function

Tags: python, function, recursion

```
def bunnies(n,months,quantity):
    print(quantity)
    if n == months:
        return quantity
    else:
        quantity=quantity+quantity
        bunnies(n+1,months,quantity)



months=int(input("How many months ?"))
quantity=1
n=0
bunnies_total=bunnies(n,months,quantity)
print(bunnies_total)
```

For some reason my function returns `None`, I can't figure it out.

Comment: You must return the result of the bunnies call in your else.

Comment: fix your indentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `else` branch doesn't return anything, which means in python it will just return `None`. Slap a `return` on the call to `bunnies`, and you should be OK:

```
def bunnies(n,months,quantity):
    if n == months:
        return quantity
    else:
        quantity=quantity+quantity
        return bunnies(n+1,months,quantity) # Here
```

Comment: I have to wait 7 minutes.